# La variable del path donde se ejecuta el script es válida pero no funciona en forfiles ni en robocopy

Tags: batch, .bat

Estoy tratando de hacer un fichero .bat (batch file) que borre recursivamente ficheros y carpetas de la ruta donde se ejecuta el propio bat (se entiende por hacer doble click en el fichero)

El caso es que el borrado recursivo lo tengo claro, pero quiero guardar al principio del script la variable de la ruta actual. Buscando he visto que debería funcionar con un myvar=%cd% y de hecho funciona, pero luego cuando quiero usar %myvar% da error siempre indicando que no se ha encontrado la ruta. Haciendo un ECHO de %myvar% sí que retorna el path correctamente por lo que no entiendo porqué después, a la hora de ejecutar el forfiles y el robocopy ya no le sirve la variable

Script:

```
:: set output off by default
@echo off   

:: clean screen
cls             

:: assign the current path to the variable "scriptPath"
SET scriptPath=%cd% 

:: change directory to current to prevent deleting other files by error
cd %scriptPath%     



:: for each file found
    :: /P = indicates the path to look for older files and folders
    :: /S = make it recursively
    :: /D -x = looks for files with 'x' days older at least
    :: /C = execute the following command
        :: /S /Q = delete folders even if they are not empty, withouth prompting


forfiles /p %scriptPath% /s /m *.* /D -5 /c "cmd /c del @path /s /q"
@ROBOCOPY %scriptPath% %scriptPath% /S /MOVE
```

Distintas cosas que también he probado con robocopy

```
@ROBOCOPY "%scriptPath%" "%scriptPath%" /S /MOVE
@ROBOCOPY "%%scriptPath%%" "%%scriptPath%%" /S /MOVE
@ROBOCOPY %%scriptPath%% %%scriptPath%% /S /MOVE
```

Distintas cosas que he probado con FORFILES

```
forfiles /p %scriptPath% /s /m *.* /D -5 /c "cmd /c del @path /s /q"
forfiles /p @path /s /m *.* /D -5 /c "cmd /c del @path /s /q"
forfiles /p "@path" /s /m *.* /D -5 /c "cmd /c del @path /s /q"
```

No sé las vueltas que he dado ya y las combinaciones que he probado pero no doy con la tecla.
Al final creo que es muy sencillo:

- Limpiar pantalla
- Asignar el directorio donde se ejecuta el .bat a la variable scriptPath
- Hago un "cd" por seguridad simplemente
- ForFiles elimina todos los ficheros más viejos de 5 días, pero deja los directorios sin borrar
- Robocopy elimina precisamente todos los directorios vacíos

Comment: a que te refieres con recursivamente por que si lo que quieres borrar archivos normal es `del *.*` pero no se si eso es recursivo

Comment: Ostras ! hace 10 meses de esto :_) La verdad es que ya no recuerdo cómo lo resolví, de hecho lo hice en la anterior empresa en la que estaba y ahora mismo no sería capaz de replicar la solución. De todos modos, gracias por el comentario @patata

Comment: Me alegro de que conseguistes resolverlo pero acostumbrate a cuando has resuelto un problema y aun nadie te ha resuelto auto responderte para que a si la gente que tenga el mismo problema que tu pueda resolverlo.